# C++ Calling function pointers

Tags: c++, callback, functor, ostream

I have a system of callback functions to organize the initialization and run time processes of my engine. I have a class that manages all of these function pointers and they are stored in a STL vector container. They are called through a wrapper class like (*iterator)->execute();

When I call these pointers I do it in a for loop. So if I have 20 function pointers registered it will go through all 20 and find the matching type and call the function through the wrapper class.

My question is, when the pointer function is called does the loop wait for that function to end its execution and then continue looping or does the loop continue to call functions while the first function is running? Mind you this is all happening on the same thread.

I did a little testing and it seems that the loop does not pause while executing other function. This seems like some sort of psuedo-threading? ... that doesn't seem right. The results may not be correct, however, as I am using std::cout to print results to the console, so I don't know if this appears to be happening due to some ostream functionality i'm unaware of.

Comment: It would be easier if you could post some of the code? However, the `for` loop will wait for each function to complete before invoking the next function. One of the functions could spawn a thread though.

Comment: Most likely this is because you are not flushing the stream with each std::cout.  Are you terminating lines with std::endl or with "\n"?

Comment: check it using some kind of global variable that you check against for every call? if your code is not asynchronous this behavior should not happen.

Comment: I think, you need an [Exorcist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exorcist) who has a degree in Comp Science ;-)  - victim seems to be the Stream, unless your function pointers are posting work on a work queue or something, but function will return quickly even in that case.

Answer (score 2):

> when the pointer function is called does the loop wait for that function to end its execution and then continue looping or does the loop continue to call functions while the first function is running?

In this respect the call through a pointer is not different from a call of a named function: they both complete *synchronously*, i.e. the caller waits for the function to return.

The most likely reason has to do with console *buffering* information, which may result in significant delays displaying what's queued.

Answer (score 2):

`for` loops and using function pointers will not create threads.  Call [flush](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/flush/) and you will see the text you have queued up.  You could also use a debugger to track what is going on.